# UIImageView changing when app is run

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, ios4, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView that has some stuff on the edges that I don't want to show.  So in IB I just pulled in the edges of the border and made the view mode "center" so it clips off the edges.  But when I run the app, it shows them.  Any specific settings or BOOL's I should be looking at for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep: the `clipsToBounds` property. If that doesn't work, try its `layer`'s `masksToBounds` property.